# Debug with Magento 2.4.4

Tags: magento2.4, log, debugging

Hello i'd like to understand how to enable all possible error log that can happen in my Magento 2.4.4 in production mode since website is live.
I checked that in var/log folder there are usefull files but it's all there?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In production mode Magento writes to log all designed messages except debug level. First of all you need to check `var/log/system.log` (in some cases more useful `var/log/support_report.log`) and `var/log/exception.log`.

Some Magento modules can write separate logs and they will be stored in the same `var/log` directory also (usually).

If you want to properly handle Magento logs I suggest to configure `logrotate`. It helps you to organize and archive your logs.

Also Magento writes Report log for any unhandled errors and writes into `var/report` directory.

I'm strongly suggest to don't forget to enable PHP error log on production and monitor it as well. See `log_errors` and `error_log` parameters.